# Copying a directory from a remote HDFS local file system to my local machine

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, scp

I have a directory on my local hdfs environment, I want to copy it to my local computer. I am accessing the hdfs using ssh (with a password).

I tried many suggested copy command but did not work.

What I tried:

```
scp ‘username@hn0-sc-had:Downloads/*’ ~/Downloads
```

as mentioned in this [link](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/xfer/scp.html). 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried looking at `hdfs dfs -copyToLocal`?  Do you have hdfs commands available on your local machine?  This link may help: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#copyToLocal

Comment: No. I don’t have hdfs commands on my local macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCP will copy from the remote Linux server.

HDFS does not exist on a single server or is a "local filesystem", therefore SCP is not the right tool to copy from it directly

Your options include

1. SSH to remote server
2. Use `hdfs dfs -copyToLocal` in order to pull files from HDFS
3. Use SCP from your computer to get the files you just downloaded on the remote server

Or

1. Configure a local Hadoop CLI using XML files from remote server
2. Use `hdfs dfs -copytoLocal` directly against HDFS from your own computer

Or

1. [Install HDFS NFS Gateway](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html)
2. Mount an NFS volume on your local computer, and copy of files from it